# How to sort negative values - dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame that looks as follows:

```
> df <- data_frame(g = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A'), h = c(7, 3, 5, 9, 2, 4), i = c(-7, -3, 5, -9, 2, 4))
> df
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  g         h     i
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A         7    -7
2 A         3    -3
3 B         5     5
4 B         9    -9
5 B         2     2
6 A         4     4
```

I want an output first sorted by h using groups from g and then sort I.

```
> df
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  g         h     i
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A         7    -7
6 A         3    -3 
2 A         4     4
4 B         9    -9
3 B         5     5
5 B         2     2
```

I tried this but negative values are not sorting correctly.

```
df %>% group_by(g)%>% 
  arrange(g, desc(h), desc(i))
```

Comment: there are no duplicates in h so the sorting key on I doesn't matter

Comment: As Michael has correctly put it, the sorting on second column will work when there are duplicate in first column, otherwise how is it possible to sort the database on two diff criteria simultaneously?

Comment: That actually. helped. Thank you. @MichaelChirico

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to sort `i` by the absolute value.

```
df %>% group_by(g)%>% 
  arrange(g, desc(h), desc(abs(i)))

# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   g [2]
  g         h     i
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A         7    -7
2 A         4     4
3 A         3    -3
4 B         9    -9
5 B         5     5
6 B         2     2
```

Comment: i should be -7, -3,4 for A.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
> df[with(df, order(g, -h, -i)), ]
  g h  i
1 A 7 -7
6 A 4  4
2 A 3 -3
4 B 9 -9
3 B 5  5
5 B 2  2
```